# irreduciblity of $\ell$-adic representation attach to the elliptic curve over $\mathbf{Q}$ with complex multiplication

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, elliptic-curves, galois-representations

Currently I am reading the book, Fermat’s Last Theorem written by Darmon, Diamond and Taylor. (You can find this pdf online http://www.math.mcgill.ca/darmon/pub/Articles/Expository/05.DDT/paper.pdf)
In proposition 2.8 part (b), it says if one has an elliptic curve defined over $\mathbf{Q}$, for a prime number $\ell$, consider the $\ell$-adic representation attached to the tate module of this elliptic curve:
$$\rho_{E,l}:G_{\mathbf{Q}}\rightarrow GL_{2}(\mathbf{Z}_{\ell})$$
Then $\rho_{E,\ell}$ is absolutely irreducible for all $\ell$. The proof of this statement refers to Serre's book 'Abelian l-adic Representations and Elliptic Curves'. However, in that book, it only shows the irreducibility for an elliptic curve without complex multiplication. I am wondering the idea of proving the irreducibility in complex multiplication case; any references would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An elliptic curve over $\mathbf Q$ cannot have complex multiplication (defined over $\mathbf Q$). It's possible for a rational elliptic curve to have extra endomorphisms, but these will only be defined over a finite extension.

But let's instead take an elliptic curve $E$ over a number field $K$ with complex multiplication. Then the associated Galois representation is *reducible**!

Indeed, if 
$$\rho_{E,\ell}:G_K\to \mathrm{GL}_2(\overline{\mathbf Q}_\ell)$$
is the associated $\ell$-adic representation, then its not too hard to check that
$$\mathrm{End}(E)\otimes_\mathbf Z\overline{\mathbf Q}_\ell\hookrightarrow\mathrm{End}(\rho_{E,\ell}).$$

In particular, if $\mathrm{End}(E)\ne \mathbf Z$, then $\mathrm{End}(\rho_{E,\ell})$ is not a field, so $\rho_{E,\ell}$ is reducible. Its subrepresentations are one dimensional Galois representations, which by class field theory, correspond to the Grossencharacters of $E$.

In fact the above map is an isomorphism (by Faltings' theorem). So if $\mathrm{End}(E) = \mathbf Z$, then $\mathrm{End}(\rho_{E,\ell})$ is a field, so $\rho_{E,\ell}$ is irreducible.

If $E$ does not have complex multiplcation over $K$, but obtains extra endomorphisms over a finite extension, then the above argument shows that $\rho_{E, \ell}$ is irreducible. However, $\rho_{E, \ell}$ will not be surjective. By Mackey theory, since $\rho_{E, \ell}$ is irreducible, but $\rho_{E, \ell}|_{G_L}$ is reducible for some $L$, we find that $\rho_{E, \ell}$ is induced from a character of a quadratic extension. In particular, its image cannot be $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbf Z_\ell)$.

*By reducible, I mean that it becomes reducible over the algebraic closure $\overline{\mathbf Q}_\ell$. It may still be irreducible over $\mathbf Z_\ell$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Maybe there is a terminology confusion here. By 'defined over $\mathbf{Q}$', I mean the elliptic curve has a Weierstrass model whose coefficients are in $\mathbf{Q}$. So in this case, I think an elliptic curve defined over $\mathbf{Q}$ could have complex multiplication, e.g $y^2=x^3-x$ whose $\mathrm{End}(E)=\mathbf{Z}[i]$. Also, could you explain why $End(\rho_{E,l})$ is not a field. i.e why $\mathrm{End}(E)\otimes\overline{\mathbf Q}_\ell$ could not be $\overline{\mathbf Q}_\ell$.

Comment: In the case of $y^2 = x^3-x$, the isogeny which corresponds to $i$ is given by $(x,y) \mapsto (-x, iy)$. As a map of algebraic curves, this map is not defined over $\mathbf Q$. In that sense, $E/\mathbf Q$ does not have CM, but $E/\mathbf Q(i)$ does (one often says that $E$ has *potential* CM).

Comment: For your second question, you can think dimensionally: if $\mathrm{End}(E)\otimes\mathbf Q$ is an $n$-dimensional $\mathbf Q$ vector space, then $\mathrm{End}(E)\otimes\overline{\mathbf Q}_\ell$ will be an $n$-dimensional $\overline{\mathbf Q}_\ell$ vector space.

Comment: Maybe I see your confusion? The tensor product is taken over $\mathbf Z$. So $\mathbf Z[i]\otimes_\mathbf Z \overline{\mathbf Q}_\ell$ is $\overline{\mathbf Q}_\ell ^2$.

Comment: Here's another way of thinking about it: $5$ splits in $\mathbf Q(i)$, so $\mathbf Q(i)\otimes_\mathbf Q\mathbf Q_5$ is canonically isomorphic to $\mathbf Q_5^2$. Conversely, $\mathbf Q(i)\otimes_\mathbf Q\mathbf Q_3 = \mathbf Q_3(i)$. But in any case, tensoring up to the algebraic closure gives $\overline{\mathbf{Q}}_\ell^2$.

Comment: Thank you for clarification, I got it. Also, if we consider $y^2=x^3-x$ then this elliptic curve gives $V_{l}(E)=T_{l}(E)\otimes\mathbf{Q}_l$ being irreducible $\mathbf{Q}_l[G_{\mathbf{Q}}]$-module, but $V_l(E)\otimes\overline{\mathbf{Q}_l}$ is not irreducible according to the reasoning you gave. But isn't irreduciblility for '$\mathbf{Q}_l$' gives absolutely irreduciblity? (Since one can consider the eigenspace of complex conjugation, in this setting the characteristic polynomial of complex conjugation is $x^2-1$. It has two 1-dimensional eigenspaces over $\mathbf{Q}_l$.

Comment: Say $E^{+}$ and $E^{-}$ being two eigenspaces over $\mathbf{Q}_l$. If $V_l(E)\otimes\overline{\mathbf{Q}_l}$ is reducible, say it has W which is stable under $G_{\mathbf{Q}}$ (it should be 1-dimensional $\overline{\mathbf{Q}_l})$ vector space), then consider $W\bigcap E^{+}$ and $W\bigcap E^{-}$. One of them should be non-empty (say $W\bigcap E^{+}$ is non-empty), as a result $W=E^{+}\otimes\overline{\mathbf{Q}_l}$. This gives a contradiction since $E^{+}$ is not stable under $G_{\mathbf{Q}}$ action.

Comment: A $k$-representation is absolutely irreducible if it is also irreducible as a $\overline k$ representation. I'm not sure I understand your argument involving complex conjugation. Just because $E^+\otimes \overline{\mathbf Q}_\ell$ is stable, doesn't mean that $E^+$ is stable.

Comment: I should clarify: $V_l(E)$ is still irreducible as a $\overline{\mathbf{Q}}_l[G_{\mathbf Q}]$ module. It is also irreducible as a ${\mathbf{Q}}_l[G_{\mathbf Q(i)}]$-module, but is reducible as a $\overline{\mathbf{Q}}_l[G_{\mathbf Q(i)}]$ module.

Comment: Dear @Mathmo123, I am wondering why the representation is not necessarily reducible over $Q_{\ell}$ (but only over $\overline{Q_{\ell}}$. Since $E$ has CM (say over an imaginary quadratic field K), the representation $G_K \to Aut(T_{\ell} E)$ factors through a compact abelian group (see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/13349), and continuous irreps of abelian groups are necessarily 1-dimensional, no?

Comment: @Watson Continuous irreps of 1-dimensional representations *over algebraically closed fields* are one-dimensional. Otherwise, think about the real vs. complex representations of any cyclic group of order $\ge 3$.

Comment: @Mathmo123: good catch indeed. A representation $G \to GL_n(k)$ be can irreducible without the composite $G \to GL_n(k) \subset GL_n(K)$ to be irreducible.

Comment: @Watson you can also see it on the level of endomorphism algebras. For example, if $E$ has CM by $\mathcal Q_(i)$, then $\mathbb Q(i)\otimes \mathbb Q_3$ is a field (because $3$ is inert), but $\mathbb Q(i)\otimes \overline{\mathbb Q}_3$ is not.