# Is $H^1_{et}( \overline{C},\mathbb Q_l)$ irreducible as a Galois representation?

Tags: algebraic-curves, arithmetic-geometry, etale-cohomology, galois-representations

Let $C$ be a smooth, projective, geometrically connected curve over $\mathbb Q$. We know that for any prime $\ell$ outside a finite set of primes, we have a $G_{\mathbb Q}$-representation $H^1_{et}( \overline{C},\mathbb{Q}_{\ell})$ whose dimension is twice the genus of the curve. Lets call any such $\ell$ as *good*. Here $\overline C$ is the curve base changed to $\overline{\mathbb Q}$.

Then a couple of idle questions:

1. Is it possible that $H^1_{et}( \overline{C},\mathbb{Q}_{\ell})$ is reducible as a $G_{\mathbb Q}$ representation for one of these good $\ell$? If so, is there any geometric consequence of this for the curve or it's Jacobian?
2. Is it possible for all the $H^1_{et}(\overline{C}, \mathbb{Q}_l)$ to be simultaneously reducible for all the good $\ell$?

Comment: This should be false at least over some imaginary quadratic fields K, by taking some elliptic curve E with CM by K. Then 
$$G_K   \to   
Aut( \overline{\Bbb Q_{\ell}}  \otimes_{\Bbb Z_{\ell}}   T_{\ell}(E) )$$ 
is reducible for all primes $\ell \nmid N_E$ (see e.g., https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3112343). The Tate module is isomorphic (as Galois representation) to the dual of $H^1$ in this case, I think.

Comment: Aha, this is exactly the kind of thing I was hoping for! So I did a bit of digging and found that this implies that the $L$ function of such an elliptic curve with CM factors into $L$-functions of Hecke Grossencharacters. I will now try to see if I can prove this kind of thing for higher genus curves whose Jacobian has a "big" endomorphism ring. 
Thank you, if you make this an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, in complete generality, if $(\rho_\ell\colon G_{\mathbb Q}\to \mathrm{GL}_n(\overline{\mathbb Q}_\ell))$ is a compatible system of $\ell$-adic Galois representations, then, conjecturally, $\rho_\ell$ is absolutely irreducible for some $\ell$ if and only if it is absolutely irreducible for all $\ell$.

This conjecture is wide open in general, but it is well-understood in your case, due to Faltings' theorem. To make things easier, I'm only going to talk about absolute irreducibility.

Let $J$ be the Jacobian of $C$. By a deep theorem of Faltings, the natural embedding
$$\mathrm{End}_{\mathbb Q}(J)\otimes_{\mathbb Z}\overline{\mathbb{Q}}_\ell\hookrightarrow\mathrm{End}(T_\ell(J)\otimes\overline{\mathbb Q}_\ell)$$
is an isomorphism. By Schur's lemma, a representation is irreducible if and only if its endomorphism ring is a field. Thus,

> $H^1(\overline C, \mathbb Q_\ell)$ is absolutely irreducible if and only if $\mathrm{End}_\mathbb Q(J) = \mathbb Z$.

The embedding, which is elementary, shows that $H^1(\overline C, \mathbb Q_\ell)$ is absolutely reducible if $\mathrm{End}_\mathbb Q(J) \ne \mathbb Z$. The content of Faltings' theorem is in the converse.

Note that this condition is clearly independent of $\ell$.

In particular, it's extremely common for $H^1(\overline C, \mathbb Q_\ell)$ to be absolutely reducible. @Watson has already mentioned CM curves in the comments. But another extremely important example is the modular curves $X_0(N)$. Here, the Galois representation decomposes as a direct sum of two-dimensional representations, each corresponding to a modular form in $S_2(\Gamma_0(N))$. Indeed, this process is exactly how one attaches Galois representations to weight $2$ modular forms!

Comment: Very nice answer! I like the example about $X_0(N)$ at the end! By the way, do you have any reference (in the literature) for the conjecture you state at the beginning?

Comment: @Watson it's one of those folklore conjectures - I can't think of a paper where it's state explicitly, although if you need something to cite, I can think of a few papers where it's alluded to. It probably follows from a very general version of the Tate conjecture.

Comment: @Watson it follows from the general Langlands philosophy. If some $\rho_\ell$ decomposes as $\sum_i\sigma_i$, then each $\sigma_i$ should correspond to some automorphic representation $\pi_i$. But then each of the $\pi_i$'s should have its own associated compatible system $\rho_{i, \ell}$, and then Chebotarev +  Brauer--Nesbitt tells you that $\rho_\ell = \oplus_i\rho_{i, \ell}$ for all $\ell$. Unfortunately, for arbitrary compatible systems, the only way to prove cases of this conjecture seems to be to prove cases of the Langlands conjecture, hence why it is wide open.

Comment: Thank you for a great answer! My original motivation was to find varieties whose $L$-function could be expressed using sums/products of $L$-functions of modular forms generalizing the  in the case of elliptic curves. And now thanks to your final paragraph, I've realized I already know some!! The zeta functions of Jacobians of modular curves.